# Secure login method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm currently working on the login system of my WebApp, which I'm developing in ASP.NET MVC. I am currently using the .NET Framework 4.8.x. Now I have developed the UI and my backend is running. This allows the user to log in and out without any problems. But my question now is whether my way of working is safe?

This is what my login function looks like:

**Note:** Currently, I am saving the password as it is for testing purpose but later i will change it as a hashed one with salt added to it.

```
            String mycon = "my-connection-string";
            SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mycon);
            String myquery = "select * from loginDetails where uName=@uName and paswrd=@paswrd";
            scon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myquery, scon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", lc.userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paswrd", lc.password);
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                Session["username"] = lc.userName.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"]= "Invalid Username or Password";
            }
            scon.Close();
            return View(lc);
```

This is what my logout function looks like:

```
            if (Session["username"] != null)
            {
                Session.Clear();
                Session.RemoveAll();
                Session.Abandon();
            }
            return View();
```

Do I have any mistakes here? It doesn't seem very safe to me if only the username is checked by the server. Wouldn't it be safer if I used a SessionID and it expired after 24 hours for example? Unfortunately I don't know how to do that. I know how the automatic logout works via session-timeout. But I think the `SessionIDManager` would help me a lot.  However, I don't use an entity framework and therefore I can't give the class `SessionIDManager` a context instance.

To authorize the user I use a filter. It looks like this:

```
 public class Authorize : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "Controller", "Login"},
                    { "Action", "Index"},
                });
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an improvement suggestion for me?

Is it safe to use the session variable for authorization?

Comment: It's worth taking a look at the solution provided by microsoft called identity, it will make it easier at various points of your system when it comes to session / login / security. Link:  [Microsoft Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score -1):

You can use login with model (secure method) ;

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    // LoginDetails -> Your Model Name && db -> Your Database Context Name
    LoginDetails loginDetails = db.LoginDetails.Where(item => item.username == username && item.password == password).FirstOrDefault();
    if(loginDetails == null)
        // Login Failed
    else
        // Login Successful
}
```

Comment: This is not secure - the password is stored in the database in plaintext. That's a big security violation and should never be done. Passwords should be one-way hashed and salted - this means that anyone that obtains access to the database won't suddenly have everyone's password.

Comment: this is model method.Sending model and turn new model(not with query!).You cannot say not useful sorry but this is unacceptable.

Comment: Of course you should not save the password as plain text. But I think that is also clear to the questioner. More important for this question is whether it is safe to store the username only in the session variable for subsequent queries to the web server. Or should I generate a SessionID? And if so, then how? So to be more precise: What should I do if I login successfully?

Comment: @Ali Why do you think that is clear to the questioner? They make no mention that they're aware of that.

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN I *can* say it's not useful if you tell people that it's secure when it actually isn't. If you don't wan't to be downvoted, then fix your example so that it's secure.

Comment: I use this method more than 5 years.I will give you login link and prove me unsafe by decrypting?

Comment: The fact that you've been storing passwords in plaintext in your database for 5 years does not inspire confidence. There is no "decrypting" to be done. If I was able to access your database, I would suddenly have the usernames and passwords for all your users. And those users probably reused those credentials across other websites, allowing me to cause further damage. Whereas if you had been security conscious and not stored the passwords in plaintext, you could have notified your users of the breach and advised them to update their passwords well before an attacker brute forced the passwords.

Comment: you think you are going to have enough thinking about it.this is worrying sorry

Comment: mason is absolutely right. You have to hash and salt passwords. But again, it's about whether it's safe to use the session variable and whether it's sufficient to store only the username in the session variable. Or should you rather generate a session ID? And if you have to generate a session ID, it's about how to do it. I know this very well, because the questioner is my colleague.

Comment: A potential hacker could store another user's username in his session variable and then send it to the server. This would authenticate him. Whereby a session ID is generated by the server and the assignment and validity of this session ID could be documented. In a database, for example. If the session ID were a long hash value, no potential hacker could guess it. And through an SSL encryption between client and server no "Man in the middle" attack would be possible.

Comment: After a certain period of inactivity (e.g. 24 hours) the server could then delete the session ID from the database and the client would be logged out because its session ID is no longer valid. Is this correct? Is that safe?

Comment: You are right bro.But he should not discourage people.This is not true.So you are right but mason not.